# mule testing, NoClassDefFoundError org.springframework.core.OrderComparator$OrderSourceProvider

Tags: maven, mule

I have a maven mule project (generated with the new mule project in Anypoint Studio). When running the tests in Anypoint Studio everything works great. However, when I try to run the build, including the tests, with maven it fails:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org/springframework/core/OrderComparator$OrderSourceProvider
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.OrderComparator$OrderSourceProvider
```

This problem happens for both JUnit and MUnit tests. Anyone have an idea what is missing, how I can get this to work?

The dependencies in the pom.xml looks like this:

```
<!-- Mule Dependencies -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Xml configuration -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Mule Transports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Mule Modules -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-extensions-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-extensions-spring-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-http</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-module-db</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-transport-ftp</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-munit-support</artifactId>
        <version>${mule.munit.support.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
        <artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId>
        <version>${munit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: can you share your pom or a portion of it (at least its dependencies section)?

Comment: added dependencies, there are almost no changes from the generated values from Anypoint Studio

Comment: Which mule version are you using?

Comment: latest version: 3.7.0

Comment: I was able to get this to work by adding spring-core and spring-context to the classpath. I am not sure why it works in Anypoint Studio, and the generated pom should include everything required to build the project.

Comment: Hi, adding spring libraries directly I don't think is a good idea. This can cause additional problems. Could be that you have another library using a different version of spring core overriding the one used by mule ?

Comment: I dont know, this was simply a project generated by anypoint studio. Very easy to recreate the problem, just create a new mule project and add a test. Try to run this test with maven.

Comment: I got this error, had to go to MUnit > Configure MUnit Maven Support if anyone else runs across this

Answer (score 0):

It seems version issues please try latest spring core version

Comment: please include such suggestions as comments instead of posting as answer